Dynamically changing dropdowns in Jupyter notebook widgets
I'm currently using yDataProfiling (the re vamped pandas profiling) in a Jupyter Notebook on Vertex Workbench on our GCP platform.
The purpose of this is to enable the Data Engineering team to be able to get a view of the table they are interested in and dive into the metric which yData Profiling provides.
I have successfully been able to hard code project ID's, Dataset names and Table names in order to display the HMTL output for the desired table, so this works great.
As there are a number of Datasets and tables within the project, the users want to be able to use a drop down box via a widget in the notebook to choose the dataset of interest, and then the table of interest would be another drop down, dynamically created based on the 1st drop down, there is a number of benefits if this is possible.
Has anyone successfully been able to generate such widgets, or used the GCP python libraries?

What have you actually looked into specifically? "Search, and research" is emphasized as the second section heading of StackOverflow's 'How do I ask a good question?' guide. The post and my comments here has some related information for doing this with ipywidgets that are meant to be used in Jupyter notebook files. You may want to first check out all the examples linked to find one closer to your situation.
